# SQL Server Insert with where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I have a query like this:

```
Insert into Table1 (Code)
Values ('ss23')
Where Table1.sequence between '0' and '999'
```

I get the following error :

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.

Comment: `insert` queries do not have `where` clauses. There is `insert ... select from ... where...`, but you're not using that.

Comment: Are you trying to insert new rows or update existing rows? What database platform, MS SQL Server, Oracle etc?

Comment: do you want to do an `update` instead?

Comment: Unfortunately, SQL server does not let you invent your own syntax for doing things :-)

Comment: Thanks Milen Pavlov. Update worked.

Comment: Please consult the [official MSDN documentation on `INSERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx) - that command does not allow a `WHERE` clause - you say what values to insert, and those will be inserted - unconditionally

Comment: Add a column constraint of you want to avoid Table1.sequence values outside the '0' - '999' range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `insert` to insert new data into your table. But you rather want to update your exsiting data. Use `update` for this

```
update Table1
set code = 'ss23'
Where sequence between 0 and 999
```